# Application gvies me a "Cannot read property" error, but only the layout is affected

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vue-component, crud, vuejs3

I am really scratching my head at this.

I am making a CRUD application, and this problem started when I was working on the Edit component.
I am getting the error **Cannot read property 'id' of null**
BUT! The interesting thing is that the data actually DOES get updated, both in the application and on the server side.
The error however affects the layout. First of all, the delete button appears two places in the template instead of one, and instead of redirecting me to the main page when I update, the main page appears like a new div on the edit page. I have no idea what is going on.

Here are the different components/composables:

**The Details component:** Here the information about a specific document is stored based on it's ID.

```html
<template>
        <div v-if="playlist" class="playlist-details">
            <div class="playlist-info">
                <div class="cover">
                    <img :src="playlist.coverUrl">
                </div>
                <h2> {{ playlist.title }}</h2>
                <p> {{ playlist.description }} </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button @click="handleDelete">Delete</button>
        <EditSong :playlist="playlist" />
</template>

<script>
import EditSong from '../components/EditSong'
import useDocument from '../composables/useDocument'
import getDocument from '../composables/getDocument'
import useStorage from '../composables/useStorage'
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
export default {
    props: ['id'],
    components: { EditSong },
    setup(props) {
        const { document: playlist } = getDocument('playlists', props.id)
        const { deleteDoc } = useDocument('playlists', props.id)
        const router = useRouter();
        const { deleteImage } = useStorage()

      const handleDelete = async () => {
          await deleteImage(playlist.value.filePath)
          await deleteDoc()
          confirm('Do you wish to delete this content?')
          router.push({ name: "Home" });
      }

        return {
            playlist,
            handleDelete
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**Here is the Edit component:** This is where I edit and update the data inside the Details component. This is where I am getting the TypeError.
It has something to do with the **props.playlist.id** field

```html
<template>
    <div class="edit-song">
      <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
      <input type="text" required placeholder="title" v-model="title">
      <input type="text" required placeholder="description" v-model="description">
      <button v-if="!isPending">Update</button>
      <button v-else disabled>Updating...</button>
   </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router' 
import useDocument from '../composables/useDocument'
import useCollection from '../composables/useCollection'
export default {
    props: ['playlist'],
    setup(props) {
        const title = ref('')
        const description = ref('')
        const { updateDoc } = useDocument('playlists', props.playlist.id)
        const { error } = useCollection()
        const isPending = ref(false)
        const router = useRouter();

        const handleSubmit = async () => {
            await updateDoc({
                title: title.value,
                description: description.value,
            })
                isPending.value = false
                if(!error.value) {
                router.push({ name: "Home" })
             }
        }

        return {
            title,
            description,
            handleSubmit,
            isPending,
            error
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**And last, this is the Update composable:** that stores the update function

```js
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { projectFirestore } from '../firebase/config'

const useDocument = (collection, id) => {
    const error = ref(null)
    const isPending = ref(false)

    let docRef = projectFirestore.collection(collection).doc(id)

    const updateDoc = async (updates) => {
        isPending.value = true
        error.value = null
        try {
            const res = await docRef.update(updates) 
            isPending.value = false
            return res
        }catch(err) {
            console.log(err.message)
            isPending.value = false
            error.value = 'Could not update document'
        }
    }

    return {
        error,
        isPending,
        updateDoc
    }

}

export default useDocument
```

Answer (score 1):

The likely scenario is `getDocument()` returns a `ref` to `null` for `document`, which gets updated asynchronously:

```js
const getDocument = (collection, id) => {
  const document = ref(null)

  someAsyncFunc(() => {
    document.value = {...}
  })

  return {
    document
  }
}
```

Since the `document` (renamed to `playlist`) is bound to the `EditSong` component, it receives both the initial value (`null`) and then the asynchronously populated value, which leads to the behavior you're seeing.

One solution is to conditionally render `EditSong` on `playlist`:

```html
<EditSong v-if="playlist" :playlist="playlist" />
```

Another is to move the `updateDoc` initialization into `handleSubmit`, and add a `null`-check there:

```js
const handleSubmit = async () => {
    if (!props.playlist) return
    const { updateDoc } = useDocument('playlists', props.playlist.id)
    await updateDoc(...)
}
```